# magento configrable product collection 1500 with pagination but showing time out not loading

Tags: magento, collections, pagination, product

please visite my url and seee 
https://staging.raptorsupplies.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=baldwin

you click on first product also you can see this product showing 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AvOp9.png)

if click on then it will be showing error like

and if click on other product then it open and working, because variation/collection list have less but it is in 1500 variation

i have create pagination for this request but i am still facing error

you can see my code where is error i think error in pagination but i am get it show please any one can help me

[enter image description here][2]

```
 public function getConfigAttribOption($childProductList, $attribbid = NULL, $AllchildProductList = null) {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); //die;

        if ($attribbid > 0) {
            $SqlAttributeID = "select distinct attribute_id from eav_attribute_option where option_id in($attribbid)";
            $RowAttributeID = $this->executeQuery($SqlAttributeID);
            foreach ($RowAttributeID as $arrKey => $Arrval) {

                $arrAttributeId[] = $Arrval['attribute_id'];

            }
            $attributeids = implode(',', $arrAttributeId);
            $sqlConfigurableAttribute = "select a.attribute_id as id,a.frontend_label as label,a.attribute_code as attribute_code,group_concat(distinct i.value) as option_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.value SEPARATOR '&|&') as option_value from catalog_product_entity_int as i join eav_attribute as a on i.attribute_id=a.attribute_id JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS o ON i.value=o.option_id  where o.store_id=".$storeId." and (a.attribute_id in(81,92) OR a.attribute_id>20000) and entity_id in($childProductList) AND  a.attribute_id NOT IN($attributeids) group by i.attribute_id having count(distinct i.value)>1";

            $arrCount = 0;
mysql_query('SET SESSION group_concat_max_len=10000');

            foreach ($arrAttributeId as $key => $val) {
                if ($arrCount == count($attribbid) - 1) {
                    $sqlCheckedAttribute.=" union all SELECT a.attribute_id AS id,a.frontend_label AS label,a.attribute_code AS attribute_code,IF(COUNT(DISTINCT i.value)>1,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.value),'') AS option_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.value SEPARATOR '&|&') AS option_value FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS i JOIN eav_attribute AS a ON i.attribute_id=a.attribute_id JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS o ON i.value=o.option_id  WHERE o.store_id=".$storeId." and (a.attribute_id in(81,92) OR a.attribute_id>20000) AND entity_id in(" . $AllchildProductList . ") AND a.attribute_id=" . $val . " GROUP BY i.attribute_id ";
                } else {
                    $sqlCheckedAttribute.=" union all SELECT a.attribute_id AS id,a.frontend_label AS label,a.attribute_code AS attribute_code,IF(COUNT(DISTINCT i.value)>1,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT i.value),'') AS option_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.value SEPARATOR '&|&') AS option_value FROM catalog_product_entity_int AS i JOIN eav_attribute AS a ON i.attribute_id=a.attribute_id JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS o ON i.value=o.option_id  WHERE o.store_id=".$storeId." and (a.attribute_id in(81,92) OR a.attribute_id>20000) AND entity_id in(" . $AllchildProductList . ") AND a.attribute_id=" . $val . " GROUP BY i.attribute_id ";
                }
                $arrCount = $arrCount + 1;
            }
            $sqlConfigurableAttribute = $sqlConfigurableAttribute . $sqlCheckedAttribute;
        } else {
            $sqlConfigurableAttribute = "select a.attribute_id as id,a.frontend_label as label,a.attribute_code as attribute_code,group_concat(distinct i.value) as option_id,GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT o.value SEPARATOR '&|&') as option_value from catalog_product_entity_int as i join eav_attribute as a on i.attribute_id=a.attribute_id JOIN eav_attribute_option_value AS o ON i.value=o.option_id  where o.store_id=$storeId and (a.attribute_id in(81,92) OR a.attribute_id>20000) and  entity_id in($childProductList) group by i.attribute_id having count(distinct i.value)>1";
        }
        $sqlConfigurableAttribute = $sqlConfigurableAttribute . " order by id"; //die;

        $productAttributeOptions = $readConnection->fetchAll($sqlConfigurableAttribute);
        return $productAttributeOptions;
    }

    public function executeQuery($query) {
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $readConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
        return $readConnection->fetchAll($query);
    }

    function getRelativeOptionBlock($productId = null, $attribbid = null, $pageno = null) {
        $encrypted_string=$this->getRequest()->getParam('active_filters'); 
        $decrypted_string=urldecode(base64_decode($encrypted_string)); 
        if($decrypted_string){
         $attribbid=$decrypted_string;
         $productId= $this->getProduct()->getId(); 
        }
        if ($attribbid && $productId) {
            //$childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($productId);
            //$childProductList = implode(',', $childProducts[0]);
            $AllchildProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($productId);
            $AllchildProductList = implode(',', $AllchildProducts[0]);
            $attribb = explode(',', $attribbid);
            $query = 'SELECT  eav_attribute.attribute_code FROM eav_attribute JOIN eav_attribute_option ON eav_attribute.attribute_id=eav_attribute_option.attribute_id WHERE option_id IN(' . $attribbid . ')';
            $results = $this->executeQuery($query);
            $attribvalue = $results['0']['attribute_code'];
            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
            $childProductsColl = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')
                    ->getUsedProductCollection($product)
                    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

            foreach ($results as $res) {

                $childProducts = $childProductsColl->addFieldToFilter($res['attribute_code'], $attribb);
            }
            $childProductList = array();
            foreach ($childProducts as $cp2) {
                $childProductList[] = $cp2->getId();
            }
            $childProductList = implode(',', $childProductList);
} elseif ($productId) {
            $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($productId);
            $childProductList = implode(',', $childProducts[0]);
        } else {
            $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($this->getProduct()->getId());
            $childProductList = implode(',', $childProducts[0]);
        }
        $attributeOptions = array();
        $productAttributeTh = array();
        $productAttributeId = array();
        $resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
        $writeConnection = $resource->getConnection('core_write');
        $querytemp="SET group_concat_max_len=100000";
        $writeConnection->query($querytemp);
        $productAttributeOptions = $this->getConfigAttribOption($childProductList, $attribbid, $AllchildProductList);
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setOptionlength(count($productAttributeOptions));
        $html = "";
        $html .= "<div class='box-container list' style='margin-left: 40px;'>";

        foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
            $productAttributeTh[] = $productAttribute['label'];
            $productAttributeThId[] = $productAttribute['id'];
            $productAttributeThCode[] = $productAttribute['attribute_code'];
            $productAttributeId = array();
            $productAttributeVal = array();
            $productAttributeId = explode(',', $productAttribute['option_id']);
            $productAttributeVal = explode('&|&', $productAttribute['option_value']);
            if((int)$productAttribute['id'] == 81)
            {
                $this->brandcount = count($productAttributeVal);
            }
            if((int)$productAttribute['id'] == 81 && count($productAttributeVal) ==1)
                continue;
            $attribute_to= count($productAttributeId);
            $attribute_option=array();
            for($i=0;$i<$attribute_to;$i++){
            $attribute_option[$productAttributeId[$i]]=$productAttributeVal[$i];
            }
            asort($attribute_option);

            $label =$productAttribute['label'];

            $html .= "<div class='inner-box-container list-content'>";
            $html .= "<p class='new_align' title='".ucwords($productAttribute['label'])."'>" .ucwords($label) . "</p>";
            ///$productAttributeLbel = $productAttribute['label'];
            $productAttributeLbel = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', $productAttribute['label']);
            $html .= "<script> multiselected('" . str_replace(' ', '', $productAttributeLbel) . "')</script>";
            $html .= "<select class='" . str_replace(' ', '', $productAttributeLbel) . "'>";
            //echo"<select >";

            foreach ($attribute_option as $OptionKey => $OptionVal) {
                if((int)$productAttribute['id'] == 81 && count($attribute_option) ==1)
                    continue;
                $attridarray = explode(',', $attribbid);
                if (in_array($OptionKey, $attridarray)) {
                    //echo $attribbid.$OptionVal; die;
         $html .= "<option value='" . $OptionKey . "' title='title'>". $OptionVal . "</option>";
                } else {
         $html .= "<option value='" . $OptionKey ."' >" . $OptionVal . "</option>";
                }
            }
            $html .= "</select>";
            $html .= "</div>";
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->setAttributeIds($productAttributeThId);


        $html .= "</div><br class='clearBoth' />";
        return $html;
    }

    function getRelativeHeaderBlock($productId = null, $attribbid = null) {
                $encrypted_string=$this->getRequest()->getParam('active_filters'); 
        $decrypted_string=urldecode(base64_decode($encrypted_string)); 
        if($decrypted_string){
         $attribbid=$decrypted_string;
         $productId= $this->getProduct()->getId(); 
        }
        if ($productId) {
            $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($productId);
        } else {
            $childProducts = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($this->getProduct()->getId());
        }
        $childProductList = implode(',', $childProducts[0]);
        $productAttributeTh = array();
        $attribidvalue= array();
        if ($attribbid) {
            $attribb = explode(',', $attribbid);
            $query = 'SELECT * FROM  eav_attribute_option where option_id in(' . $attribbid . ')';
            $results = $this->executeQuery($query);
 foreach($results as $key=>$val){
               $attribidvalue[]=$val['attribute_id']; 
            }
            //$attribidvalue = $results['0']['attribute_id'];
        }
        $productAttributeOptions = $this->getConfigAttribOption($childProductList);
        foreach ($productAttributeOptions as $productAttribute) {
            $productAttributeTh[$productAttribute['id']] = $productAttribute['label'];
        }
        $Productdetail = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
        ?>
```

Comment: please post code and edit question that can clearly inform the problem

Comment: thanks please check my code

Comment: try printing query and run directly in database to check is query running correctly.

Comment: Hi Thanks Gulshan Maury, i dont understand  please explain me in details. thank you

Comment: its working correctly my friend  but i am asking, it take more loading time see my website and images